# Android use name of unpublish app for new app with new package name

Tags: android, google-play

I have old app on google play which i going to unpublish, i create new version of app with new package name, can i use app name (which user see on google play) unpublish app to my new app with different package name

Comment: You can if the package name of the app is different, as you said

Comment: May be this link will be helpful to you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184295/publishing-same-app-with-different-names-in-the-play-store

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the app name is not required to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

only the package name com.example.yourapp that should be unique, but for the App name your free to do whatever you want but you might encounter some troubles of copyright or in search engine side